# Convert a form of BNF grammar to g4 grammar

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4, parser-generator

I'm trying to covert this BNF grammar for validating boolean expression which is currently being used in Swift. Now want to implement similar parser in Java. I came across Antlr4 lib and want to use it to generate parser for the same grammar. I'm not very familiar with antlr4. Can someone please provide me some guidance? This is what I have so far.

```
Expr                ::= <ConcatenationExpr>;
NonInfixExpr        ::= <BracketExpr>
                      | <Function>
                      | <Literal>
                      | <Accessor>;
BracketExpr         ::= '(' <Expr> ')';
Accessor            ::= ('$' <AccessorComponent> | <AccessorComponent>) ('.' <AccessorComponent> )*;
AccessorComponent   ::= 'Identifier' ':' 'Identifier' | 'Identifier';
Function            ::= 'Identifier' '(' ')' | ('Identifier' '(' <Expr> (',' <Expr>)* ')');
Literal             ::= 'True'
                     | 'False'
                     | 'Null'
                     | 'Number'
                     | 'Text';
ConcatenationExpr   ::= <AndExpr>
                     | <ConcatenationExpr> '&' <AndExpr>;
AndExpr             ::= <OrExpr>
                     | <AndExpr> '&&' <OrExpr>;
OrExpr              ::= <EqualityExpr>
                     | <OrExpr> '||' <EqualityExpr>;
EqualityExpr        ::= <ComparisonExpr>
                     | <EqualityExpr> ('==' | '=' | '!=' | '<>') <ComparisonExpr>;
ComparisonExpr      ::= <AddExpr>
                     | <AddExpr> ('<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=') <AddExpr>;
AddExpr             ::= <ExponentialExpr>
                     | <AddExpr> ('+' | '-') <ExponentialExpr>;
ExponentialExpr     ::= <MultExpr>
                     | <ExponentialExpr> '^' <MultExpr>;
MultExpr            ::= <NonInfixExpr>
                     | <MultExpr> ('*' | '/') <NonInfixExpr>;
```

I tried to convert to g4 and this is what it looks like.

```
grammar VALIDATE;

Expr
    : ConcatenationExpr ';'
    ;

NonInfixExpr
    : BracketExpr 
    | Function 
    | Literal 
    | Accessor
    ;

BracketExpr 
    : '(' Expr ')'
    ;

Accessor
    : ('$' AccessorComponent | AccessorComponent ) ('.' AccessorComponent )*
    ;

AccessorComponent
    : 'Identifier' ':' 'Identifier' | 'Identifier'
    ;

Function
    : 'Identifier' '(' ')' | ('Identifier' '(' Expr (',' Expr)* ')')
    ;

Literal
    : 'True' | 'False' | 'Null' | 'Number' | 'Text'
    ;

ConcatenationExpr
    : AndExpr 
    | ConcatenationExpr '&&' AndExpr
    ;

AndExpr
    : OrExpr | AndExpr '&&' OrExpr
    ;

OrExpr
    : EqualityExpr | OrExpr '||' EqualityExpr
    ;

EqualityExpr
    : ComparisonExpr | EqualityExpr ('==' | '=' | '!=' | '<>') ComparisonExpr
    ;

ComparisonExpr
    : AddExpr | AddExpr ('<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=') AddExpr
    ;

AddExpr
    : ExponentialExpr | AddExpr ('+' | '-') ExponentialExpr
    ;

ExponentialExpr
    : MultExpr | ExponentialExpr '^' MultExpr
    ;

MultExpr
    : NonInfixExpr | MultExpr ('*' | '/') NonInfixExpr
    ;
```

I'm stuck at antlr4 VALIDATE.g4 step. I'm not sure I did the conversion right.

```
error(119): VALIDATE.g4::: The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [MultExpr] and [ExponentialExpr] and [AddExpr] and [EqualityExpr] and [OrExpr] and [AndExpr] and [ConcatenationExpr]
error(99): VALIDATE.g4::: grammar VALIDATE has no rules
```

Comment: ANTLR does not support left-recursion across multiple rules. You'll need to either  combine all your expression rules into a single rule `Expr` with the alternatives sorted by precedence; or rewrite the grammar to remove the left recursion.

Comment: *"Can someone provide me with guidance"* and *"I am stuck"* are not questions.  However, Google did find the following for me when I searched for "antlr left recursion tutorial" :  https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687334/Left-Recursion+Removal

Comment: @StephenC Note that this information is outdated. Unlike ANTLR3, ANTLR4 does support left-recursion within a single rule, so the simplest solution to OP's problem is really just to put everything into one expression rule.

Answer (score 1):

The original grammar has no mutual left recursion - that was only introduced in the converted version by using `&&` in `ConcatenationExpr` where it should have read `&`. Once that is fixed, the grammar has only direct left recursion which ANTLR 4 should be able to cope with.

You could even completely remove left recursion by rewriting recursive rules, such that e.g. `ConcatenationExpr` would become

```
ConcatenationExpr
     ::= AndExpr ( '&' AndExpr )*
```

If this is done for all recursive rules, the resulting grammar is LL(2).